# Hadoop and MapReduce, How do I send the equivalent of an array of lines pulled from a csv to the map function, where each array contained lines x - y;

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce

Okay, so I have been reading a lot about Hadoop and MapReduce, and maybe it’s because I’m not as familiar with iterators as most, but I have a question I can’t seem to find a direct answer too. Basically, as I understand it, the map function is executed in parallel by many machine and/or cores. Thus, whatever you are working on must not depend on prior code being executed for the program to make any kind of speed gains. This works perfectly for me, but what I’m doing requires me to test information in small batches. Basically I need to send batches of lines in a .csv as arrays of 32, 64, 128 or whatever lines each. Like lines 0 – 127 go to core1’s execution of the map function, lines 128 – 255 lines go to core2’s, etc., .etc . Also I need to have the contents of each batch available as a whole inside the function, as if I had passed it an array. I read a little about how the new java API allows for something called push and pull, and that this allows things to be sent in batches, but I couldn’t find any example code. I dunno, I’m going to continue researching, and I’ll post anything I find, but if anyone knows, could they please post in this thread. I would really appreciate any help I might receive.

**edit**

If you could simply ensure that the chunks of the .csv are sent in sequence you could    preform it this way. I guess this also assumes that there are globals in mapreduce.

```
//** concept not code **//

GLOBAL_COUNTER = 0;
GLOBAL_ARRAY = NEW ARRAY();

map()
{ 

GLOBAL_ARRAY[GLOBAL_COUNTER] = ITERATOR_VALUE;

GLOBAL_COUNTER++;
if(GLOBAL_COUNTER == 127)
{
//EXECUTE TEST WITH AN ARRAY OF 128 VALUES FOR COMPARISON
GLOBAL_COUNTER = 0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get a chunk of lines from your CSV file into the mapper, you might consider writing your own InputFormat/RecordReader and potentially your own WritableComparable object.  With the custom InputFormat/RecordReader you'll be able to specify how objects are created and passed to the mapper based on the input you receive.

If the mapper is doing what you want, but you need these chunks of lines sent to the reducer, make the output key for the mapper the same for each line you want in the same reduce function.

The default TextInputFormat will give input to your mapper like this (the keys/offsets in this example are just random numbers):

```
0    Hello World
123  My name is Sam
456  Foo bar bar foo
```

Each of those lines will be read into your mapper as a key,value pair.  Just modify the key to be the same for each line you need and write it to the output:

```
0    Hello World
0    My name is Sam
1    Foo bar bar foo
```

The first time the reduce function is read, it will receive a key,value pair with the key being "0" and the value being an Iterable object containing "Hello World" and "My name is Sam".  You'll be able to access both of these values in the same reduce method call by using the Iterable object.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
int count = 0
map (key, value) {
      int newKey = count/2
      context.write(newKey,value)
      count++
}

reduce (key, values) {
    for value in values
        // Do something to each line
}
```

Hope that helps.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If the end goal of what you want is to force certain sets to go to certain machines for processing you want to look into writing your own [Partitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Partitioner.html). Otherwise, Hadoop will split data automatically for you depending on the number of reducers.

I suggest reading [the tutorial on the Hadoop site](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html) to get a better understanding of M/R.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to send N lines of input to a single mapper, you can user the [NLineInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/NLineInputFormat.html) class. You could then do the line parsing (splitting on commas, etc) in the mapper.

If you want to have access to the lines before and after the line the mapper is currently processing, you may have to write your own input format. Subclassing FileInputFormat is usually a good place to start. You could create an InputFormat that reads N lines, concatenates them, and sends them as one block to a mapper, which then splits the input into N lines again and begins processing.

As far as globals in Hadoop go, you can specify some custom parameters when you create the job configuration, but as far as I know, you cannot change them in a worker and expect the change to propagate throughout the cluster. To set a job parameter that will be visible to workers, do the following where you are creating the job:

```
job.getConfiguration().set(Constants.SOME_PARAM, "my value");
```

Then to read the parameters value in the mapper or reducer,

```
public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) {

        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        String someParam = conf.get(Constants.SOME_PARAM);

        // use someParam in processing input
}
```

Hadoop has support for basic types such as int, long, string, bool, etc to be used in parameters.